# dajaxice register functions

Tags: django, function, dajaxice

I'm using `Django v1.2.3` and `Dajaxice v0.2`. My setup looks exactly like the one in the [docs](http://docs.dajaxproject.com/dajaxice/installation.html), but my function is not being registered. When I try to call this function it seems to be `undefined` and when I open the `Dajaxice.core.js` there is no registered function. Because I CAN open the `Dajaxice.core.js` it looks to me like everything is working except the registration of functions. Can this have something to do with `Django v1.2`?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem once. My solution isn't that nice, but it worked for me. As you can read in the [dajaxice docs](http://docs.dajaxproject.com/dajaxice/production-environment.html) you can serve the file statically when your done `{% dajaxice_js_import "js/dajaxice.core.js"%}`. That's what I did, and I hardcoded the register of my function.
After a server restart I changed it to `{% dajaxice_js_import %}` and removed the hardcoded stuff, but the function was still registered.

Answer (score 1):

When registering function using DAJAXICE_FUNCTIONS option in settings.py you should call it as

```
Dajaxice.app.func(callback)
```

When using decorator @dajaxice_register call it as

```
Dajaxice.prj.app.func(callback)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to register a function with dajax. Have you tried both?
There is this way:

```
dajaxice_functions.register(myexample)
```

and this way:

```
@dajaxice_register
def myexample(request):
```

[Creating my first dajaxice function](http://docs.dajaxproject.com/dajaxice/create-my-first-dajaxice-function.html)

Comment: Yes I tried both, without success. I also tried to register two functions with the same name, just to throw an exception. But even this didn't have an effect.